# Issue when GroupBy an ArrayList object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have issue when I use GroupBy an ArrayList object in Kotlin.

I have JSON like here:

```
 {
  "securityAccountList": [
    {
      "accountNumber": "001548900001",
      "accountName": "Tjandraningrum",
      "currency": "IDR",
      "debtInstrument": "0",
      "equityInstrument": "0"
    },
    {
      "accountNumber": "001548900001",
      "accountName": "Tjandraningrum",
      "currency": "IDR",
      "debtInstrument": "0",
      "equityInstrument": "0"
    },
    {
      "accountNumber": "001548900001",
      "accountName": "Tjandraningrum",
      "currency": "USD",
      "debtInstrument": "22",
      "equityInstrument": "66"
    }
  ]
}
```

I generate object by GSON like this:

```
 data class ContentModel(
        @SerializedName("securityAccountList") var securityAccountList: ArrayList<SecurityAccountList> = arrayListOf()
    ) 

    data class SecurityAccountList(

        @SerializedName("accountNumber") var accountNumber: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("accountName") var accountName: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("currency") var currency: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("debtInstrument") var debtInstrument: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("equityInstrument") var equityInstrument: String? = null

    )
```

now I want to grouping by field currency and I want result like this

```
{
  "securityAccountList": [
    {
      "accountNumber": "001548900001",
      "accountName": "Tjandraningrum",
      "currency": "IDR",
      "debtInstrument": "0",
      "equityInstrument": "0"
    },
    {
      "accountNumber": "001548900001",
      "accountName": "Tjandraningrum",
      "currency": "USD",
      "debtInstrument": "22",
      "equityInstrument": "66"
    }
  ]
}
```

but the result not changed, still 3 securityAccountList,
this my code for grouping:

```
val  newSecurityAccountList= contentModel.securityAccountList
     newSecurityAccountList.groupingBy { it.currency }
     newSecurityAccountList.sortBy { it.currency }
```

> Note: contentModel.securityAccountList is ArrayList of object JSON the newSecurityAccountList not changed value.

please your advice, sorry for my English.

Comment: What do you mean by grouping by currency? If there are two Json objects which have same currency, what do you wanna do with them? Do you wanna make a List of all such objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun List<SecurityAccountList>.customFilter(): List<SecurityAccountList> =
    groupBy { it.currency }.map {
// HERE you can do whaterver you need.
        it.value
            .filter { item-> item.currency >= 0 }
            .maxByOrNull { item-> item.accountName.length }
    }.filterNotNull()
```

Using in code

```
val returnlist = yourListBeforeFilter.customFilter()
```

For more details tell us what exactly you need.
You can as well use here `sortBy`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are expecting `groupingBy` to modify the list. In fact it won't, but will instead return a new `Grouping` object which can be used to gather the results into a new, different list.

It can be confusing, because `sortBy` does mutate the list, whereas the similar-looking `groupBy` and `groupingBy` functions return a new object or copy and don't mutate the original.

The best way to be sure whether a function is going to mutate the existing object or create a new object is to check its documentation. In Kotlin, most of the standard library functions are non-mutating, because Kotlin encourages immutability.

You could try replacing your code with something like:

```kotlin
val groupedAccounts = contentModel.securityAccountList.groupBy { it.currency }
```

Note how the variable stores the result of the call to `groupBy`, not the original `securityAccountList`.